# Visual Studio not finding boost include files in release mode (works in debug)

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, include

I'm using boost with Visual Studio 2013 Express.

Visual Studio finds the `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>` in Debug mode, but not in Release mode.

When I try to compile in Release mode, it says:

`Error  1   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/filesystem.hpp': No such file or directory`

When I right click on the `#include` directive to open the file manually, it works in Debug configuration, but again not in Release, there it says:

`File 'boost/filesystem.hpp' not found in current source file's directory or in build system paths.`

I checked the build configurations and

- C/C++ - > General -> "Additional Include Directories"
- Linker -> General -> "Additional Library Directories"
- Linker -> Input -> "Additional Dependencies"

Are the same for both configurations.

Do I need to edit the "build system paths", as the error says? I thought that was what the three options above do.

What else could cause this problem?

Comment: I can't do that, I don't have administrator rights, but if that is really the solution I will ask if I can get them temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check you've checked the settings of the project that actual failed to build. I had the same issue when using *boost::optional*. I just overlooked that another project (*UnitTests*) was failing, rather than the project I suspected (*CppPlaygroundLib*) due to misinterpreting the build output by focussing on the line containing the error message:

> 1>------ Build started: **Project: UnitTests**, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
>
> 1>  FooTests.cpp
>
> 1>c:\projects\playground\cppplayground\**cppplaygroundlib**\foo.h(3): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
>
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

After I had added the missing boost path in *C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories* my solution compiled successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Project Property Pages in Visual Studio are not the same for both configurations.
At the Property Page, just set Configuration (top-left) to Release and set configuration for the release build independently.