# Visual Studio Boost Not Including in Release Mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, visual-studio-2013

I am attempting to include boost, specifically `boost/foreach` and `boost/filesystem`, into a Visual Studio 2013 C++ application. My current include setup works in debug mode, but not in release mode.

I have included the full path to the `boost_1_60_0` directory in the project properties under C++->General->Additional Include Directories. I have also added the full path to the `boost_1_60_0\stage\lib` directory under Linker->General->Additional Library Directories. I made both of these changes while in release mode.

I have tried the suggestions from this post: [Visual Studio not finding boost include files in release mode (works in debug)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198383/visual-studio-not-finding-boost-include-files-in-release-mode-works-in-debug). I have not been able to find any other pertinent information, even after much searching.

All suggestions given will be much appreciated!

Comment: I can tell you that boost-1.60 does work with release mode Visual Studio 2013. I have my entire codebase (several million lines of code) that I tested with this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Doing some research, I had gotten the suggestion to add dependencies to linker->input->->additional dependencies. After removing this from my release properties, all started to work.

Comment: That is very weird that modifying linker settings would have anything to do with headers.